# Duplicate objects including associations and ActionText content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails 6 application I have Menus and they have Pages. Pages have ActionText in the "content" attribute.

**models/menu.rb**

```
class Menu < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :pages
end
```

**models/page.rb**

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :menus
  has_rich_text :content
end
```

How do I duplicate (like, really duplicate) pages and keep their menu association and action_text content? AR's .dup breaks both associations and content. deep_clone says nothing about AT content and amoeba seems dead?

My stuff also have some active_storage attachments btw :)

Comment: Hey @Nick, did you solve this issue? Curious on how you did it.

Comment: Wasn't able to find a fix yet so for the time being I am duplicating each AT/AS attachment after duplicating the object.

Comment: @NickM how do you do that? Do you have any small code example that you could share? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at ActiveRecord's [dup](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-dup) method for a good explanation. It only provides a "shallow" copy since the extent of a "deep" copy is application-specific.

Just override `dup` in your model to include the associations you wanted. I often append "(copy)" to the name and clear slugs.

So, here's an example to get you started:

```rb
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :menus
  has_rich_text :content

  # Deep duplicate (copy)
  def dup
    super.tap do |duplicate|
      duplicate.attributes = {
        title: title.concat(" (copy)"), # change duplicate's title
        slug: nil, # clear the slug if you're using friendly_id
        content: content.dup,
        menu_ids: menu_ids
      }
    end
  end
end
```